# Synology NAS DSM I want to create a new SSL certificate but always get the failure "The operation failed. please login again and retry"

Tags: ssl, certificate, synology

as described in the header, I can't create a new SSL certificate with Let's Encrypt on my Synology NAS.
I tried everything, reboot, turn off the firewall, (..) but yet I always get the same failure "The Operation failed. please login again and retry." 
Does someone know where the problem could be?

The domain works, I can access it from the internet but it always uses the standard certificate of synology and thats valid..
Thank you for your help and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem some months ago. For Let's Encrypt you must provide proper data. If you have multiple alternative names (like www.website.com;website.com;mail.website.com) they must all be valid and provided similar to this list.